# macros c programming #define min(a,b) (a < b ? a : b)

Tags: c, macros

I am reading up on macros and i wanted to know what this #define does? I don't understand the "?" and the ":". Is it saying that if a

```
#define min(a,b) (a < b ? a : b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a macro feature, that's a core C feature, a ternary operator called the conditional operator.

```
x = a < b ? a : b
```

is essentially:

```
if (a < b)
   x = a
else
   x = b
```

i.e.: `(cond ? a : b)` has the value of `a` if `cond` is true, otherwise `b`.

Comment: No, it's not called the ternary operator. It's called the conditional operator. It is *a* ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

The ? has nothing to do with macros, it's an Ternary Operator. It is similar to the if-else operator.

A simple example:

```
c = (a < b ? a : b)
```

This code says that when `a<b` is true, a is assigned to c, if `a<b` is false b is asigned to c.
You can read more by googling "Ternary operator".